# JavaFX Nested TableView Spacing

Tags: java, javafx, layout, tableview, nested-table

So I am trying to create a nested table using JavaFX and have run into an spacing issue. I am using the standard method to create the main table, nothing special there. The nested table though: I am following a guide I found at this link https://edencoding.com/tableview-customization-cellfactory/ Everything is working the way that it should with the exception of the space that gets added to the row when I insert the nested table. I want the row of the main table to be the same height of the whole nested table but its quite alot larger than that and I cant seem to resize it.

I have tried the following:

1. In the cell.itemProperty listener I set the cell maxHeight.
2. I set the max height of the nested TableView.
3. In the second link at the bottom you can see a picture of when I used a ChoiceBox instead of the TableView. This does make the row the correct size (it fits the choice box).
4. Removed the ConstrainedResize policy
5. Set the max height of the cell to a fixed amount just before returning the cell from the cell.itemProperty listener.
6. Calling cell.resize(n,n) just before returning the cell from the cell.itemProperty listener.

Heres the code for creating the table. This method is in the controller class. The BlendedWordRecall class is a very simple POJO and BlendClass is an interface but again, very basic getters and setters nothing fancy.

```
private TableView getBlendingTableView(List<BlendedWordRecall> recalls) {
        ObservableList<BlendedWordRecall> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        data.addAll(recalls);
        
        TableView<BlendedWordRecall> table = new TableView<BlendedWordRecall>();
        table.setMinWidth(1250);
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String> wordCol = new TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String>("Word");
        wordCol.setMinWidth(150);
        wordCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            return new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getWord());
        });
        
        TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String> recallDateCol = new TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String>("Recall Date");
        recallDateCol.setMinWidth(230);
        recallDateCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(cellData.getValue().getDateOfRecall().toInstant(),ZoneId.systemDefault());
            return new SimpleStringProperty(ldt.format(dateTimeFormat));
        });
        
        TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String> correctCol = new TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String>("Correct?");
        correctCol.setMinWidth(230);
        correctCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            String booleanString = cellData.getValue().isWasCorrect() == true ? "Correct" : "Incorrect";
            return new SimpleStringProperty(booleanString);
        });
        correctCol.setCellFactory(column -> {
            return new TableCell<BlendedWordRecall, String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
        
                    if (item == null || empty) {
                        setText(null);
                        setStyle("");
                    } else {
                        if (item.equals("Correct")) {
                            setText("Correct");
                            setStyle("  -fx-font-size: 14px;\r\n" + 
                                            "   -fx-font-family: \"Comic Sans MS\";\r\n" + 
                                            "   -fx-font-weight: bolder;\r\n" + 
                                            "    -fx-text-fill: #37ff00;");
                        } else {
                            setText("Incorrect");
                            setStyle("  -fx-font-size: 14px;\r\n" + 
                                            "   -fx-font-family: \"Comic Sans MS\";\r\n" + 
                                            "   -fx-font-weight: bolder;\r\n" + 
                                            "    -fx-text-fill: #E60000;");
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        });
        
        TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String> sightCol = new TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String>("Sight Read?");
        sightCol.setMinWidth(150);
        sightCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            String sightString = cellData.getValue().isWasSightRead() == true ? "True" : "False";
            return new SimpleStringProperty(sightString);
        });
        
        TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String> recallTimeCol = new TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String>("Recall Time");
        recallTimeCol.setMinWidth(150);
        recallTimeCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            String timeString = String.format("%.2f", cellData.getValue().getRecallDuration())+" Sec";
            return new SimpleStringProperty(timeString);
        });

        TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String> blendsCol = new TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String>("Blends");
        blendsCol.setMinWidth(300);
        blendsCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            return new SimpleStringProperty("yes");// Set just so the cell.itemProperty will fire all the time
        });
         blendsCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
            TableCell<BlendedWordRecall, String> cell = new TableCell<>();
            
            cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, old, newVal) -> {
                if (newVal != null) {
                    //////////////////////////////// Create nested table //////////////////////////////////////
                    ObservableList<BlendClass> blendList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                    SingleLetterBlendRecall slbOne = new SingleLetterBlendRecall("a / A", "A" , "b / B", "B");
                    SingleLetterBlendRecall slbTwo = new SingleLetterBlendRecall("b / B", "B" , "c / C", "C");
                    blendList.addAll(slbOne,slbTwo);
                    TableView<BlendClass> blendTable = new TableView<BlendClass>();
                    blendTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
                    TableColumn<BlendClass, String> firstCol = new TableColumn<BlendClass, String>("First Sound");
                    firstCol.setMinWidth(150);
                    firstCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
                        return new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getFirstSoundName());
                    });
                    
                    TableColumn<BlendClass, String> secondCol = new TableColumn<BlendClass, String>("Second Sound");
                    secondCol.setMinWidth(150);
                    secondCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
                        return new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getSecondSoundName());
                    });
                    blendTable.getColumns().addAll(firstCol, secondCol);
                    blendTable.setItems(blendList);
                    blendTable.setMaxHeight(40 + (30*blendList.size()));
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    cell.graphicProperty().bind(Bindings.when(cell.emptyProperty()).then((Node) null).otherwise(blendTable));
            }
        });
        return cell;
    });
        table.getColumns().addAll(wordCol, recallDateCol, correctCol, sightCol, recallTimeCol, blendsCol);
        table.setItems(data);
        
    return table;
}
```

[Table made with current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cpVk.png)

[Table made using a choice box instead of a nested table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGjiH.png)

[Table made without resizing the nested table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GWff.png)

Based on the fact that the table in the first pic has the same size of rows as the table in the third pic, I am pretty sure that this is a timing issue. Like the layout is happening before I resize the table or something. Any ideas on where to go from here would be awesome, thanks guys.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out finally. Hopefully it will help someone else who runs into the same issue. When building the nested table I was originally just setting the max height which made the nested table the right size but the cell that contained it was the original size of the nested table before i set its max height. Apparently if you set max, min and preferred height of the nested table then it behaves correctly in that the cell that contains the nested table will size according to the size of the nested table. Heres a picture for reference.

[Correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKfNG.png)

Heres the updated code, only two lines changed:

```
private TableView getBlendingTableView(List<BlendedWordRecall> recalls) {
        ObservableList<BlendedWordRecall> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        data.addAll(recalls);
        
        TableView<BlendedWordRecall> table = new TableView<BlendedWordRecall>();
        table.setMinWidth(1250);
        table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
        TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String> wordCol = new TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String>("Word");
        wordCol.setMinWidth(150);
        wordCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            return new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getWord());
        });
        
        TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String> recallDateCol = new TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String>("Recall Date");
        recallDateCol.setMinWidth(230);
        recallDateCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(cellData.getValue().getDateOfRecall().toInstant(),ZoneId.systemDefault());
            return new SimpleStringProperty(ldt.format(dateTimeFormat));
        });
        
        TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String> correctCol = new TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String>("Correct?");
        correctCol.setMinWidth(230);
        correctCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            String booleanString = cellData.getValue().isWasCorrect() == true ? "Correct" : "Incorrect";
            return new SimpleStringProperty(booleanString);
        });
        correctCol.setCellFactory(column -> {
            return new TableCell<BlendedWordRecall, String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
        
                    if (item == null || empty) {
                        setText(null);
                        setStyle("");
                    } else {
                        if (item.equals("Correct")) {
                            setText("Correct");
                            setStyle("  -fx-font-size: 14px;\r\n" + 
                                            "   -fx-font-family: \"Comic Sans MS\";\r\n" + 
                                            "   -fx-font-weight: bolder;\r\n" + 
                                            "    -fx-text-fill: #37ff00;");
                        } else {
                            setText("Incorrect");
                            setStyle("  -fx-font-size: 14px;\r\n" + 
                                            "   -fx-font-family: \"Comic Sans MS\";\r\n" + 
                                            "   -fx-font-weight: bolder;\r\n" + 
                                            "    -fx-text-fill: #E60000;");
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        });
        
        TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String> sightCol = new TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String>("Sight Read?");
        sightCol.setMinWidth(150);
        sightCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            String sightString = cellData.getValue().isWasSightRead() == true ? "True" : "False";
            return new SimpleStringProperty(sightString);
        });
        
        TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String> recallTimeCol = new TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String>("Recall Time");
        recallTimeCol.setMinWidth(150);
        recallTimeCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            String timeString = String.format("%.2f", cellData.getValue().getRecallDuration())+" Sec";
            return new SimpleStringProperty(timeString);
        });

        TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String> blendsCol = new TableColumn<BlendedWordRecall, String>("Blends");
        blendsCol.setMinWidth(300);
       
        blendsCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            return new SimpleStringProperty("yes");// Set just so the cell.itemProperty will fire all the time
        });
         blendsCol.setCellFactory(col -> {
             
            TableCell<BlendedWordRecall, String> cell = new TableCell<>();
            
            cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, old, newVal) -> {
                if (newVal != null) {
                    //////////////////////////////// Create nested table //////////////////////////////////////
                    ObservableList<BlendClass> blendList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                    SingleLetterBlendRecall slbOne = new SingleLetterBlendRecall("a / A", "A" , "b / B", "B");
                    SingleLetterBlendRecall slbTwo = new SingleLetterBlendRecall("b / B", "B" , "c / C", "C");
                    blendList.addAll(slbOne,slbTwo);
                    TableView<BlendClass> blendTable = new TableView<BlendClass>();
                    
                    blendTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
                    TableColumn<BlendClass, String> firstCol = new TableColumn<BlendClass, String>("First Sound");
                    firstCol.setMinWidth(150);
                    firstCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
                        return new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getFirstSoundName());
                    });
                    
                    TableColumn<BlendClass, String> secondCol = new TableColumn<BlendClass, String>("Second Sound");
                    secondCol.setMinWidth(150);
                    secondCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
                        return new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getSecondSoundName());
                    });
                    blendTable.getColumns().addAll(firstCol, secondCol);
                    blendTable.setItems(blendList);
                    blendTable.setMaxHeight(40 + (30*blendList.size()));
                    blendTable.setMinHeight(40 + (30*blendList.size()));
                    blendTable.setPrefHeight(40 + (30*blendList.size()));
                    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    cell.graphicProperty().bind(Bindings.when(cell.emptyProperty()).then((Node) null).otherwise(blendTable));
                   
            }
        });
        return cell;
    });
        
        table.getColumns().addAll(wordCol, recallDateCol, correctCol, sightCol, recallTimeCol, blendsCol);
        table.setItems(data);
        
        
    return table;
}
```